# Issue in Android App installing programmatically(AutoUpdate)

Tags: java, android, apk, android-install-apk

An issue in auto-updating.That downloads a new app if an update is available and uninstall a current application and install a new app. It all works well till target SDK 22. but After target SDK 24 or updating Phone os above API Level 2 this functionality not working Whenever I install it shows package parsing error. because of an old app is already there and we are trying to install a new app.

**targetSDK:24**

**compileSDK:28**

**minSDK:19**

Here is a piece of code:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppConstants {

    public static final String TAG = UpdateActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String appName = "XYZ.apk";
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private TextView txtDownloading;
    private NumberProgressBar numberProgressBar;
    private String updateUrl = "";

    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
        updateUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build());
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        mHideHandler.post(mHidePart2Runnable);
        numberProgressBar = (NumberProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.numberbar8);
        txtDownloading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDownload);
        try {
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        DownloadFileFromURL() {
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            }

        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(updateUrl).openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("POST");
                c.setDoOutput(false);
                c.connect();
                int lengthOfFile = c.getContentLength();
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/");
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, appName);
                if (outputFile.exists()) {
                    outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                byte[] data = new byte[AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT];
                long total1 = 0;
                while (true) {
                    int count = is.read(data);
                    if (count == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    total1 += (long) count;
                    Integer[] strArr = new Integer[1];
                    strArr[0] = DOWNLOAD_COUNT + ((int) ((100 * total1) / ((long) lengthOfFile)));
                    publishProgress(strArr);
                    fos.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
                installApp();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            try {
                numberProgressBar.setUnreachedBarColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
                numberProgressBar.setProgressTextSize(30.0f);
                if (progress[0] > 0 && progress[0] <= 20) {
                    numberProgressBar.setProgressTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E74C3C"));
                    numberProgressBar.setReachedBarColor(Color.parseColor("#E74C3C"));
                    txtDownloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E74C3C"));
                }
                if (progress[0] > 20 && progress[0] <= 40) {
                    numberProgressBar.setProgressTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3D7F"));
                    numberProgressBar.setReachedBarColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3D7F"));
                    txtDownloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3D7F"));
                }
                if (progress[0] > 40 && progress[0] <= 60) {
                    numberProgressBar.setProgressTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC73B"));
                    numberProgressBar.setReachedBarColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC73B"));
                    txtDownloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC73B"));
                }
                if (progress[0] > 60 && progress[0] <= 80) {
                    numberProgressBar.setProgressTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6DBCDB"));
                    numberProgressBar.setReachedBarColor(Color.parseColor("#6DBCDB"));
                    txtDownloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6DBCDB"));
                }
                if (progress[0] > 80 && progress[0] <= 100) {
                    numberProgressBar.setProgressTextColor(Color.parseColor("#70A800"));
                    numberProgressBar.setReachedBarColor(Color.parseColor("#70A800"));
                    txtDownloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#70A800"));
                }
                numberProgressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            numberProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void installApp() {
        try {
            File apkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/", appName);
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and resolved it using the following:

- Disabling Google Play Protect from playstore app worked the trick, i-e it was blocking the installation from external sources and i was able to get rid of the parse error.
- On Android N and above, to give access to particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps, you cant use `File Uri`, instead you have to use `Provider Uri` from FileProvider class , otherwise we get the `FileUriExposedException` such as  `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()` etc.

For more information to how to setup `FileProvider`, see this guide:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Hope this helps.